# Command Blocks In Minercaft Giving items On Kills

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Could I make it so that when I kill a player for the first time, a command block gives me an iron sword, on my second kill it gives me a diamond sword, on my third kill it gives me an enchanted item, and so on?

I also want a way to reset this, as well as a start button. I know a way that I can do this by doing `/scoreboard objectives add objectivename playerKillCount`, and then a comparator does `/give @p iron_sword`. However, if I am too far from the command block and another player is next to it, the command block will give the sword to them instead. Also, `@p` won't work for the whole world, because I have to be near it. Can somebody please help me with a way that I can do this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how to count kills then give items for example on my first kill i get iron sowrd on my second kill i get diamond sword and so do other players also a way to reset this

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this on your own? You'll get a much better reception here at Arqade if you demonstrate some effort to solve this yourself. We aren't a code on demand service, and it won't be a good experience for you if that's what you use us as.

Comment: Yes i agree to an exent.  However don't give op privs to just anyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as you said in your question, declare a scoreboard objective of type `playerKillCount` to track player kills:

```
/scoreboard objectives add PlayerKills playerKillCount
```

Next, create a dummy objective that will track which rewards a player has already been given:

```
/scoreboard objectives add KillRewardGiven dummy
```

---

Now, on a clock *(any type will do so long as you can control execution order, I'll use a 20Hz /fill clock)* you'll need two blocks for each reward. One to give the reward:

```
/give @a[score_PlayerKills_min=1,score_KillRewardGiven=0] iron_sword
```

Then another do mark that the player has already received the award:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[score_PlayerKills_min=1,score_PlayerKills=1] KillRewardGiven 1
```

Here's an image illustrating how you would do your second tier reward:

[image]

---

To reset this you can run these commands, either in chat or in a command block:

```
/scoreboard players reset * PlayerKills
/scoreboard players reset * KillRewardGiven
```

To turn it on and off, you could hook something like this up to the clock:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much my friend you helped me alot, have a virtual hug from me :D

Comment: /scoreboard players reset * PlayerKills
/scoreboard players reset * KillRewardGiven does work or do i have change the * to anything, please help

Comment: Also let the asker know to put the blocks in spawn chunks so that it works for "the whole world"?